# How to exclude lines that don't include a string from the output of an awk script?

Tags: awk, gawk

Completely new to scripting in general, and have been working on a script to go through our logs which contain entries for a variety of different things.  What I'm interested in, is the entries that log user activity (logins, clicks, etc on our site).

I've pieced together the following awk script (with a ton of help) which almost works perfectly, except it prints output for lines that don't contain a username.  I'd like to exclude them, and haven't been able to find out how to do that (I assume it's something simple).

Here is the code:

```
awk '
{       split($3, d, "@")
        match($0, /"username":"[^"]*"/)
        user = substr($0, RSTART + 12, RLENGTH - 13)
        c[d[1] OFS user]++
}
END {   for(i in c)
                printf("%4d %s\n", c[i], i)
}' mycompany.log | sort -k3,3 -k2,2
```

I'm just not sure how to exclude all lines that do not contain username from the output.

Here is a sample of a line that contains a username:

```
qtp111659197-5776 - 05-26@09:37:34:240 INFO  (TimingInfoProxy.java:41)     - com.mycompany.api.ApiHandler-0>getUniqueDataBySource(data,{"has_values":false,"last_event_triggered":"","user_info":{"username":"joe@mycompany.com","orgid":"69d467a7-9786-47e1-9c12-bb40f9bfc65d","ip":"127.0.0.1"},"date_range":{"min_date":"","start_date":"","end_date":"","trending_start_date":"","trending_end_date":""},"terms":{"and_filtering":[]}},)
```

And here's a short example of a line that doesn't:

```
main - 05-22@10:05:21:387 INFO  (ContextLoader.java:313)     - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 9519 ms
```

Comment: In what way exactly do they 'not contain' a username? is the `"username":` keystring missing, or is there an empty quoted value like `"username":""`? or something else? Please edit your post to include sample entries both with and without the username.

Comment: I edited it to include samples, but basically yes the "username": keystring is missing in lines that don't include usernames.

Comment: So basically the match part of the code tells it to find the regexp "username":"[^"]*" which in terms of our logs is username@mycompany.com   Isn't there something simple I can put in there that basically tells it not to return any output if it can't find regexp "username":"[^"]*"  in any given line of input?  (sorry I'm very new to this)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already piping to other shell commands, I'd just use grep.

```
awk '
{
...
}' mycompany.log | grep -f '"username:"' | sort -k3,3 -k2,2
```

(Note that I'm using -f because the username tag never varies.)

Edit: that's the most obvious way. An arguably "better" way would be to use awk itself, e.g.

```
awk '
/\"username\":/ {
...
}' mycompany.log | sort -k3,3 -k2,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't checking the result of `match`. The following fixes it.

> RSTART is set by invoking the match function. Its value is the
>   position of the string where the matched substring starts, or zero if
>   no match was found.

```
if(RSTART){
   user = substr($0, RSTART + 12, RLENGTH - 13)
   c[d[1] OFS user]++
}
```